Set Specific Scroll Area as soon as we open a workbook
I know what code to use to set a specific scroll area:
Sub SetSpecificScrollArea()

  Dim ws As Worksheet

  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     ws.ScrollArea = "$A$1:$K$20"
  Next ws

End Sub

But, can I get that Macro to run as soon as the workbook Opens, if so, how?

Call it from the workbook open event

There are two main ways to run a procedure when the Workbook opens.
Excel VBA - Workbook Open
We can add this code to the ThisWorkbook code module:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    SetSpecificScrollArea
End Sub

Run Macro When You Open/Close a Workbook (Excel File) - Excel VBA
Or we can add this to a public module:
Public Sub Auto_Open()
    InitPersonalMenus
End Sub


Create Reusable Procedures

The immediate issue is covered in TinMan's answer.
To dig in deeper:

Get familiar with workbook events.
To get more familiar with how the following code works, study Conceptual Topics, in particular, Call Sub and Function procedures and Pass arguments efficiently.


The 1st procedure calls the 2nd procedure passing the workbook containing this code and the address of the scroll area. The workbook in a workbook module is correctly referenced with the Me keyword or with ThisWorkbook although ActiveWorkbook would also work.
The 2nd procedure calls the 3rd procedure as many times as there are worksheets, passing each worksheet and the address of the scroll area.

ThisWorkbook Module
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    SetWorkbookScrollArea Me, "A1:K20"
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1 or modScrollArea (or ThisWorkbook)
Sub SetWorkbookScrollArea(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal ScrollAreaAddress As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        SetWorksheetScrollArea ws, ScrollAreaAddress
    Next ws
End Sub

Sub SetWorksheetScrollArea(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal ScrollAreaAddress As String)
    ws.ScrollArea = ScrollAreaAddress
End Sub

